# Apps script write script for connect html page with spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script

friends.

I'm trying to work with video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPI27L_fQC4&list=PLRmEk9smitaVGAAhgU0Pdc2sEs7yxDrEk&index=1

I need to connect spreadsheet data with html-page outside of apps-scripts' project.

At js-file for it for html-project I wrote this

```js
function addGS(){

  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHHYfQ9o25lqE_TUFK01-12wYGdI3_TkcDgBpZxbAAupak3lxXFH9wpbzAwzNXWxTw7w/exec";
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'omit', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        //referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        body: JSON.stringify({name: "olivia"}) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
      });

      document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("Click", addGS);

}
```

in apps script I wrote this:

```js
function doPost(e){

  const body = e.postData.contents;
  const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("PUTAWAY_TO");
  ws.appendRow([bodyJSON.name]);
}
```

but when I start script in apps script doPost like in video on 13:50, I get mistake at e.postData.contents "TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined". Can you help me, what I forgot to do? May be I need to include some API or module?
Thank you for help!

my last javascript from html by help Tanaike:

```js
function addGS(){
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzBO2Z2G8_i8USGMKMTEBJNgGF1pANcXdQfSS9PbshtjgTiMZloegeXz3XVUBvotziMmg/exec";
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    body: JSON.stringify({name: "olivia"})
  })
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((res) => console.log(res));
}

document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", addGS);
```

and last apps-script thanks to Tanaike:

```js
function doPost(e){
  const body = e.postData.contents;
  const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("PUTAWAY_TO");
  ws.appendRow([bodyJSON.name]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

Javascript for last question about export object to spreadsheet:

```js
function addGS(){
  var userInfo = {
      login: "Dima",
      sscc: "233425236523",
      place: "dsdsds"
  }
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw60bZu-BQ0kJ7NMkohJwZLGFHIN0cf5-Dkz-lq-Qeh9pkuDNaL/exec";
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userInfo)
  })
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((res) => console.log(res));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify your Javascript as follows.

```
function addGS(){
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHHYfQ9o25lqE_TUFK01-12wYGdI3_TkcDgBpZxbAAupak3lxXFH9wpbzAwzNXWxTw7w/exec";
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({name: "olivia"})
  })
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then((res) => console.log(res));
  document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("Click", addGS);
}
```

And also, please modify your Google Apps Script side as follows.

From:

```
  ws.appendRow([bodyJSON.name]);
}
```

To:

```
  ws.appendRow([bodyJSON.name]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

- By above flow, when `fetch` is run, the value of `ok` is returned from Web Apps and you can see it at the console.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: thank you very much for help, but I have nothing in console and records don't add to spreadsheet. I added html-code with button just in case... Can you help me?

Comment: I have changed apps-script and redeployed url link for web app, but the same trouble...

Comment: I found mistake, when I send addEvenListener outside from function I get callback with mistakes

Comment: Picture with mistakes I put on top of this theme

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your additional image, I'm worry that your Web Apps might not be correctly deployed. Because when I tested the modified script, no error occurs. The value of `ok` is returned at the console of browser. I apologize for this situation. So, in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide your current whole script for replicating your issue? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: You rnow I now have only one mistake in console.log "putaway_TO.js:24 POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwVbJtrjbIZ9BMWRY8yV9qKVvWcVJcwv20uWgm-1uTDlq3AVdmRJFpzLgjH-aEkbJJHvQ/exec net::ERR_ABORTED 401" after click button

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. I saw your updated question. Unfortunately, it seems that your current script doesn't reflect my proposed modification. How about this? If you didn't still added your current script, can you add your current whole script for replicating your issue?

Comment: I added last js on  top of answer. After click on button script return this mistake putaway_TO.js:24 POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzBO2Z2G8_i8USGMKMTEBJNgGF1pANcXdQfSS9PbshtjgTiMZloegeXz3XVUBvotziMmg/exec net::ERR_ABORTED 401

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying and adding your current script. When I saw your current script, I noticed that your script doesn't correctly reflect my proposed script. I think that this reason is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. 1. In your Javascript, `mode: 'no-cors',` is not required to be used. Please remove this. 2. Can you provide your current whole script? In your updated question, only Javascript is added. Can you add your current Google Apps Script?

Comment: I placed apps-script above and the picture with mistakes I get when erase no-cors, one meassge told me to set no-cors in script, because I did that

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying and adding more information. I think that your additional Google Apps Script is correct when the sheet of `PUTAWAY_TO` is existing in the Spreadsheet. About your Javascript, please remove `mode: 'no-cors',`. When I tested the script modified this point, no error occurred. I apologize for this situation. From this situation, I',m worry that your Web Apps might not be correctly deployed.

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov As an important point for using Web Apps, **when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. When you deployed Web Apps new version, the URL of Web Apps is changed. Please be careful this.** [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)

Comment: Thank you, I know this and after changing apps script made new deployment.

Comment: I placed apps-script above and the picture with mistakes I get when erase no-cors, one meassge told me to set no-cors in script, because I did that

Comment: if I set fetch with no-cors I get this mistake "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()"

Comment: How do you think, may be issue is in blocked port? In visual code I see that used port is 5500. may it is locked?

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. In order to correctly confirm your situation, can you share the Spreadsheet including your current script? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: Yes, I shared spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s8l-8N8dI-GGJi_mmYs2f_88VBcnzWfv3YHgk1HvIh0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: apps script is in "startTSDwork". Other apps-script I need now for copying to another place, sorry

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet and your script, I noticed that your Web Apps is deployed as `"access": "ANYONE"` and `"executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"`. If you had tested this settings, I think that the error occurs. If my understanding of your situation is correct, please modify to `"executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"` and `"access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"` and test it again.

Comment: Hooray!!!! It helped! You are the best! Thank you very much! New records go to spreadsheet! But in console log is nothing.... Is it ok?

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. If `mode: 'no-cors',` is still used for Javascript, such issue occurs. Please remove it and test it again. If that was not the solution, can you provide the detail script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: You are right, I removed this and got "ok")) thank you very much for help! You are the best!!!! Good luck!

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: sorry for last question, if I want to export object data to spreadsheet, what must I edit. I wrote my last javascript for this question above. I tryed, but it don't help. I think, I need to write something in apps script) can you help me again?)))

Comment: @Dmitriy Rudakov About your new question, I would like to support you. But, that is different from your initial question. So can you post it as new question by including more information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: sorry< my last question is not relevant, I found the decision)) thank you